# arguments defaults for docopt

Tags: r, command-line-interface, docopt

I'm using docopt in R but I expect a python solution will work for me as well.

```
library(docopt)

doc = 'Usage:
  script.r [<filename>]

Arguments:
  <filename>  The input filename [default: file.txt]
'

docopt(doc)$filename
```

gives me `NULL` when what I expect is `file.txt`. Or to put it another way, I want these two commands to have the same behavior:

```
Rscript script.r
Rscript script.r file.txt
```

Comment: Looks like a docopt design decision? https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/214

Answer (score 2):

Default values are only for options with an argument like this:

```
--filename=FILENAME  The input filename [default: file.txt]
```

Default values can not be specified for arguments. You could maybe change the you program to use an option with an argument instead?